# Passar lista de checkbox para o php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Como posso passar para uma página php uma lista de checkbox selecionados, tenho isso que me mostra os checkbox, mas estou com problemas para envia-los ao php.

```
    function SelecionaChecks() {
    var Check = document.getElementsByName("check");                
    for (var i=0;i<Check.length;i++){  
        if (Check[i].checked == true){  
            // CheckBox Marcado
            alert(Check[i].value + " selecionado.");

        }  else {
            // Nenhum checkbox marcado
        }
    }
}
```

Os meus checks estão vindos dessa marcação:

```
        <div class='row'>
        <div class='span12'>
            <div class='barra-btn table-bordered'>
                <div class='btn-group'>
                    <button class='btn btn-large' type='button' title='Marcar/Desmarcar todos' id='todos' onclick='marcardesmarcar();'><i class='icon-large  icon-ok'></i></button>
                    <button class='btn btn-large' type='button' title='Imprimir'><i class='icon-large icon-print'></i></button>
                    <button class='btn btn-large' type='button' title='Enviar mensagem' onclick="SelecionaChecks()" ><i class='icon-large icon-message-plus'></i></button>
                    <button class='btn btn-large' type='button' title='Adicionar coment&aacute;rio'><i class='icon-large icon-notes'></i></button>
                    <button class='btn btn-large' type='button' title='Relacionar com uma vaga'><i class='icon-large icon-inbox-plus'></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Desse loop nesse formulário:

```
        <div class='row'>
        <div class='span12'>
            <form id="selecao">
            <table class='table table-bordered'>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                    do { 
                    if ($totalRows_rsRegistro > 0) { 
                    // Resgatando ID´s para gerar pdf e envio de e-mails
                    $IdCandidato = $row_rsRegistro['id_candidato'];

                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td width='2%'><input type='checkbox' class='marcar' name='check' id='check' value="<?php echo $IdCandidato; ?>"/></td>
                        <td width='5%' align='center'>
                            <div class='btn-group btn-group-vertical'>
                                <button class='btn btn-small' type='button' title='Imprimir'><i class='icon-large icon-print'></i></button>
                                <button class='btn btn-small' type='button' title='Enviar mensagem'><i class='icon-large icon-message-plus'></i></button>
                                <button class='btn btn-small' type='button' title='Adicionar coment&aacute;rio'><i class='icon-large icon-notes'></i></button>
                                <button class='btn btn-small' type='button' title='Relacionar com uma vaga'><i class='icon-large icon-inbox-plus'></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td width='70%'><span class='titulo_18 bold'><a href="admin/vercurriculo.php?id=<?php echo $IdCandidato; ?>" class="a-titulo"><?php echo $row_rsRegistro['nome']; ?></a></span></br>
                        <?php echo $row_rsRegistro['email']; ?></br>
                        <?php echo $row_rsRegistro['celular']; ?></br>
                        <?php echo $row_rsRegistro['id_municipio']; ?> | <?php echo $row_rsRegistro['id_uf']; ?></td>
                        <td width='23%'><span class='titulo_14'>Dados gerais</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <?php
                } else {
                    echo "<div align='center'>N&atilde;o existe(m) curriculo(s) para ser(em) exibido(s)</div></br>";
                    }
                } while ($row_rsRegistro = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsRegistro)); 
                ?>
            </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não pode usar `<form>`?

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta Sergio.

Comment: Bom você ter editado a pergunta e acrescentado código! Agora vejo que já tem um `<form>` mas sem "action". Você quer enviar e mudar/recarregar a página ou enviar mantendo a página?

Comment: Mantendo a página Sérgio, depois entendi a sua pergunta e por isso resolvi editar o post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Está pouco claro como você dispara o processo, ie que botão você carrega para enviar dados para o lado do php (lado do servidor). Deixo um exemplo em baixo. O que você precisa é ajax, para passar dados de e para o lado do servidor.

Um exemplo de função, chamada, ajax é:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "ficheiroPHP.php", // url do ficheiro php
  type: "POST",           // tipo de método POST, GET, etc
  data: { id : menuId },  // dados a enviar, objeto.
  success: function(retorno){
     // aqui a variável "retorno" contém a resposta do ficheiro php
  }
});
```

No campo `data` é onde pode passar dados para o servidor. Aqui pode fazer de maneiras diferentes mas o mais prático é usar o .serialize(), por exemplo:

```
var dados = $("form").serialize();
```

e depois dentro do ajax:

```
data: dados,  // dados a enviar, objeto.
```

Answer (score 2):

Apenas os itens marcados são enviados para o php, para pegar todos é necessario adicionar colchetes`[]` no nome do checkbox caso contrario apenas o último valor é enviado.

mude:

```
 <input type='checkbox' class='marcar' name='check' id='check'
  value="<?php echo $IdCandidato; ?>" />
```

para:

```
<input type='checkbox' class='marcar' name='check[]' id='check'
 value="<?php echo $IdCandidato; ?>" />
```

Para listar eles basta fazer um forech:

```
if(count($_POST['check']) > 0){
   foreach($_POST['check'] as $item){
       echo $item .'<br>';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Segue como ficou o meu código de acordo com as sugestões recebidas.

```
    function SelecionaChecks() {
var checked = []; 
$("input[name='check[]']:checked").each(function () 
{
    checked.push(parseInt($(this).val()));
});

    // console.log(checked);    
    $.ajax( {
        url:'enviaEmail.php',
        type:'POST',
        data: {list:checked},
        success: function(res) {
            alert(res);
        }
    });     

}
```

Resgato os checks marcados, monto um array e passo ao meu script php.
Obrigado ao @Sergio e ao @perdeu pela grande ajuda.