# Problema com php a enviar email de formulario e checkbox alternativa

Tags: php, css, formulário

Ola preciso de ajuda pois nao percebo muito de php e não estou a conseguir por a funcionar o mail de resposta do meu formulário em condicoes. As checkbox só mandam um resposta de 1  dos artigos seleccionados e nunca mandam todos se mais de que 1 selecionado.
Gostaria de saber como posso por outro tipo de checkbox em vez de aparecer a caixa por tipo o visto no meio da foto se isso for possivel .
Deixo aqui o meu codigo.
Caso queiram ver com esta com imagens [Link](https://imprimir3d.pt/quest/index.html)

```js
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
 echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$namefirst = $_POST['name_first'];
$contacto = $_POST['contacto'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$info = $_POST['check1'];


$email_from = 'info@maildoserver.pt';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "Nova Resposta ao Formulario";
$email_body = "Tem um novo pedido de informacoes da pessoa $namefirst com o contacto nº $contacto e com o email $visitor_email. \r\n".

    "Aqui esta os produtos:\r\n $info".

    "Aqui esta os comentarios adicionais:\r\n $message".
 
$to = "meumail@gmail.com";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: thank-you.html');
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');

ul {

list-style-type: none;

}
#field_1_5 {
    display: block; /* visibility: hidden works too */
}
#field_1_6 {
    display: block; /* visibility: hidden works too */
}
#field_1_7 {
    display: block; /* visibility: hidden works too */
}
#field_1_8 {
    display: block; /* visibility: hidden works too */
}
#field_1_9 {
    display: block; /* visibility: hidden works too */
}
#field_1_10 {
    display: block; /* visibility: hidden works too */
}
#field_1_11 {
    display: block; /* visibility: hidden works too */
}
#field_1_12 {
    display: block; /* visibility: hidden works too */
}
.center {
}
.list {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin-left: 150px;
 padding-left: 0px;
 display: inline-block;
 border: solid rgba(223,223,223,0.99);
 text-align: center;
 width: 305px;
 background-color: rgba(237,237,237,1.00);
}
.list1 button {
 bottom: 30px;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 width: 170px;
 text-align: center;
}
#image1 {
 opacity: 1;
}

* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.list img {
 border: solid rgba(223,223,223,0.99);
}
body img {
 float: right;
}


body {
 background-image: url(../img/../img/Background-1080p-50-opacidade--fundo-preto.jpg);
 background-size: 1920px 1080px;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 font-weight: bolder;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 color: #FBFBFB;

}
.list1 {
 margin: 5px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 display: inline-block;
}
.list1 #field_4 {
 width: 500px;
}
.list label span {
 color: #000000;
}


h1 {
 font-size: 2em;
 font-weight: bolder;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>Questionario | MONTRAS DIGITAIS</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="">
<form id="" class="" method="post" action="email.php">
                   
                                            <div id="" class="">
                                               <br>
                                              <center><h1 >Selecione os artigos <br> e obtenha mais informações </h1></center>
                                                <br>
            
                           <ul id="" class="">
                                                   
                                                    <li class="list">
                                                        <label class="" for="field_1_5">
                                                            <span class="">
        <img src="img/Montras-Digitais.jpg" alt="Montras Digitais" width="300" title="Montras Digitais">
        </span>
                                                            <br>
                                                            <input type="checkbox" id="field_1_5" name="check1" value="Montras Digitais">
                                                            <span class="">Montras Digitais</span>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </li>
                                                    
                                                    <li class="list">
                                                        <label class="" for="field_1_6">
                                                            <span class="">
        <img src="img/MediaKiosk-II.jpg" alt="Quiosque Interactivo" width="300" title="Quiosque Interactivo">
        </span>
                                                            <br>
                                                            <input type="checkbox" id="field_1_6" name="check1" value="Quiosque Interactivo">
                                                            <span class="">Quiosque Interactivo</span>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="list">
                                                        <label class="" for="field_1_7">
                                                            <span class="">
        <img src="img/Ementas-Digitais.jpg" alt="Ementas Digitais" width="300" title="Ementas Digitais" id="image1">
        </span>
                                                            <br>
                                                            <input type="checkbox" id="field_1_7" name="check1" value="Ementas Digitais">
                                                            <span class="">Ementas Digitais</span>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="list">
                                                        <label class="" for="field_1_8">
                                                            <span class="">
        <img src="img/Impressora.jpg" alt="impressora de bebidas" width="300" title="impressora de bebidas">
        </span>
                                                            <br>
                                                            <input type="checkbox" id="field_1_8" name="check1" value="Impressora de bebedas">
                                                            <span class="">Impressora de Bebidas</span>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <br><br>
                                                    <li class="list">
                                                        <label class="" for="field_1_9">
                                                            <span class="">
        <img src="img/Ecra-Transparente.jpg" alt="Ecrans Transparentes" width="300" title="Ecrans Transparentes">
        </span>
                                                            <br>
                                                            <input type="checkbox" id="field_1_9" name="check1" value="Ecrans Transparentes">
                                                            <span class="">Ecrãns Transparentes</span>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="list">
                                                        <label class="" for="field_1_10">
                                                            <span class="">
        <img src="img/Ecra-Especial.jpg" alt="Ecrans Especiais" width="300" title="Ecrans Especiais">
        </span>
                                                            <br>
                                                            <input type="checkbox" id="field_1_10" name="check1" value="Ecrans Especiais">
                                                            <span class="">Ecrãns Especiais</span>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="list">
                                                        <label class="" for="field_1_11">
                                                            <span class="">
        <img src="img/MediaTotem.jpg" alt="Totem Digital" width="300" title="Totem Digital">
        </span>
                                                            <br>
                                                            <input type="checkbox" id="field_1_11" name="check1" value="Totem Digital">
                                                            <span class="">Totem Digital</span>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="list">
                                                        <label class="" for="field_1_12">
                                                            <span class="">
        <img src="img/Cracha.jpg" alt="Crachas Digitais" width="300" title="Crachas Digitais">
        </span>
                                                            <br>
                                                            <input type="checkbox" id="field_1_12" name="check1" value="Crachas Digitais">
                                                            <span class="wpforms-image-choices-label">Crachás Digitais</span>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </li>
                                              </ul>
                                            </div>
 <br>
 <img src="img/Logo_MediaScreen_Branco.png" alt="Logo" width="300" height="321" class="" style="float: right; margin-right: 50px;" />
 
                              <center> <div id="" class="list1">
          
                                                <label class="" for="field_1">Nome <span class="">* </span>
                                                </label>
                                                        <input name="name_first" type="text" required class="" id="field_1" size="30">
                                            </div></center>
       
  <center> <div id="" class="list1" >
 
      <label class="" for="field_2">Contacto Telefónico <span class="">*</span>
                                                </label>
                                                <input name="Contacto" type="text" required class="" id="field_2" max="12" min="9" size="30">
                                            </div></center>
        
  <center>  <div id="" class="list1" >
  
      <label class="" for="field_3">Email <span class="">*</span>
      </label>
                                                <input name="email" type="email" required class="" id="field_3" size="30">
  </div></center>
       
                          <center>     <div id="" class="list1"> 
                            <label class="" for="field_4">Comentarios Adicionais <span class="">* </span></label>
                                                <textarea name="comentario" class="" id="field_4"></textarea>
                                            </div></center>

   
                                      <center><div class="list1">
           
                                        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="" id="" value="submit">Submeter</button>
                                        </div> </center>
</form>
   
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Veja esta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/19021/5878

Comment: As chaves da Array que é enviada pelo post é a Tag `name` no input, como todos os seus inputs tem a tag `name='check1'`, o PHP entende que só há uma posição na array com esse nome.Tente mudar as tags name das checkbox para: check1, check2, check3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No atributo name, no final de seu nome, colocamos colchetes.

Quando você coloca um "name" com colchetes ele é enviado na forma de vetor ou array para o receptor.

**Exemplo:**

> se submetermos o formulário com esses elementos,

```
<input type="checkbox" id="field_1_5" name="check1[]" value="Montras Digitais">
<input type="checkbox" id="field_1_6" name="check1[]" value="Quiosque Interactivo">
<input type="checkbox" id="field_1_7" name="check1[]" value="Ementas Digitais">
<input type="checkbox" id="field_1_8" name="check1[]" value="Impressora de bebedas">
```

> e recuperarmos no PHP

```
$info = $_POST['check1'];

Print_r($info);
```

> teremos o seguinte resultado

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Montras Digitais
        [1] => Quiosque Interactivo
        [2] => Ementas Digitais
        [3] => Impressora de bebedas
    )
```

### Conclusão

- Coloque colchetes nos `name` dos checkboxes `name="check1[]"`
- No PHP faça assim

  ```
  .....................
  .....................
  $info = $_POST['check1'];

  if(count($info) > 0){
     foreach($info as $item){
         $produtos .= $item .'<br>';
     }
  }


           ....................
           ....................
           $email_body = "Tem um novo pedido de informacoes da pessoa $namefirst com o contacto nº $contacto e com o email $visitor_email. \r\n".

           "Aqui esta os produtos:\r\n $produtos".
           ..................
           ..................
  ```